# Adding a footer with same functionality as the header

Tags: fullcalendar

Can I add replicate the header buttons in the footer?

I have a rather long calendar and the user would like to be able to move forward/back when scrolled to the bottom of the calendar.

I found a note on the Google code site this would be considered for v1.5 but don't see anything in the recent docs about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[a jquery plugin](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints).  instead of replicating header buttons, why not make the header buttons [sticky](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

Comment: What do you want is to have buttons that do the same has the one's in the header, so you go ahead and make any HTML buttons you like and just add a onclick event to it. After that check documentation for something like this calendar.Fullcalendar('prev'); calendar.Fullcalendar('next'); etc ;)

Comment: I did end up using the built in methods for prev/next and it worked fine.